# How do I pass file path to command line arguements when using "open with" in Windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, launch4j

I'm new here so I'm not sure I'm doing anything wrong so please do tell me if I am.

I'm making a simple image/gif viewer in Java. I want to be able to use the extracted application (which I will wrap in an .exe with launch4j) to open image files. When choosing the image to open with it, I want it to get the file path of the image and pass it to args[0] so that the application can use it.

I'm sensing this is something that needs to be done outside of my Java code. Maybe in an installer or the wrapper I'm using but I have no idea how to do it.

I've been searching the past 3 hours to no avail. Any help is appreciated. My code so far:

```
public class MainWindow {

private JFrame frame1;
public static String imageLocation = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            imageLocation = args[0];
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame1.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(imageLocation));
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int imgWidth = img.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = img.getHeight();

        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        frame1.setTitle(imageLocation);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame1.setBounds(200, 200, imgWidth+18, imgHeight+40);

        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel("");
        imgLabel.setToolTipText(imageLocation);
        imgLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
        imgLabel.setBounds(0, 0, frame1.getWidth(), frame1.getWidth());
        frame1.getContentPane().add(imgLabel);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did think the files were passed in onto the command line by default, but if not look into how context menu items are added into the registry. You can find your entry and change it to `myapp.exe %1` in order to pass that through.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean when you say by default? If I make an .exe with launch4j and then open an image with it, should it pass its path to args[0] by default?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this - if you drag your file onto the exe, then yes, definitely. I appreciate this probably isn't the way you want to use it though! I'm assuming right click a image file, Open With, browse to your exe, then set as default. This really SHOULD feed that image file through to your exe in first parameter, but if it doesn't, or you need to pass in other command line parameters too, you can customise it in the registry, under `classes root` as I recall.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't. Nothing happens when I do that. It really seems like I have to do something else. What you are saying about the registry seems to be it but I have no idea how to do that. The user shouldn't have to do that, so I'm looking for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Actually it seems to work now that I re-built it with launch4j. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any form elements to upload files. Not an expert in JForms but I believe you need a file upload control that will pass its value to the args array in your code.